# Specified cast is not valid SQLite Empty SELECT Value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to sum a column WHERE date  BETWEEN  @from  AND  @to as shown below

```
DateTime from = DateTime.Parse(dt_From.Value.ToShortDateString());
DateTime to = DateTime.Parse(dt_To.Value.ToShortDateString());
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
con.Open();

//Total Items Sold
string query = " SELECT SUM(total) FROM acc_items_income WHERE date BETWEEN @from AND @to AND deleted = 0 ";
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@from", from));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@to", to));
```

And i'm trying to read it, As shown

```
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    double soldItems = dr.GetDouble(0);
    txtTotalSoldItems.Text = soldItems.ToString("c", naira);
}
```

My error now is, when i select from a row where the datetime is not in the database, or can't SUM a column that does not have a value, then i get this error.

Specified cast is not valid

Comment: then add another statement to the where clause `and Where total IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for DBNull values before attempting to read the column.

```
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    if (dr.IsDBNull(0)) { //Check for a null value at the 0 index
        soldItems = 0;
    } else { 
        soldItems = dr.GetDouble(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to accept my answer as what solved your problem so I can get points :)